# Problem in making tab host background translucent

Tags: android

I have created a tab host. Now when I set the background of each tab as translucent than a dark line appears between each tab. I am sending my code and snapshot to justify my answer. So anyone, please suggest to me how I can resolve this problem.

**Code for XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
    <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TabWidget
    android:id="@android:id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
    <FrameLayout
    android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    />
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

**Code for java**

```
//create tabs
                Resources res = getResources(); 
                final TabHost MainTabHost = getTabHost();  
                TabHost.TabSpec spec; 
                Intent intent; 
                
                MainTabHost.getTabWidget().setStripEnabled(false);
                
                //call calendar Activity class
                intent = new Intent().setClass(this, CalendarForm.class);
                //intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                spec = MainTabHost.newTabSpec(res.getString(R.string.text_tabHost1)).setIndicator("Calendar",
                res.getDrawable(R.drawable.calendar_ic)).setContent(intent);
                
                MainTabHost.addTab(spec);
                
                //call History Activity class
                intent = new Intent().setClass(this, HistoryForm.class);
               // intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                spec = MainTabHost.newTabSpec(res.getString(R.string.text_tabHost2)).setIndicator("History",
                res.getDrawable(R.drawable.calendar_ic)).setContent(intent);
                MainTabHost.addTab(spec);
        
                //call Statistic Activity class
                intent = new Intent().setClass(this, StatisticForm.class);
                //intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                spec = MainTabHost.newTabSpec(res.getString(R.string.text_tabHost3)).setIndicator("Statistic",
                res.getDrawable(R.drawable.calendar_ic)).setContent(intent);
                MainTabHost.addTab(spec);
                
                //setbackground Style of tabHost                                       
                MainTabHost.setCurrentTab(0); 
                MainTabHost.getTabWidget().setWeightSum(3);
                final TabWidget tabHost=getTabWidget();   
                MainTabHost.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.back_image);

               //set background translucent..                       
                MainTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0)setBackground(#50000000);
                MainTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(1).setBackground(#50000000)
                MainTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(2).setBackground(#50000000)
```

[image]

Comment: Did you make your own drawables? Are they not the same size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this will solve it, but it's worth a shot as it looks like the divider is what's causing the issue.

```
tabHost.getTabWidget().setDividerDrawable(null);
```

Comment: It was worth a shot.  I'd suggest taking a look at this page - http://joshclemm.com/blog/?p=136.  I had a lot of troubles getting my tabs to look the way I wanted and finally found this site.  This will allow you to customize every aspect of the tabs and be in control of everything.  HTH

Comment: Also, the reason for that dark line is because the two tabs are overlaying on top of each other and the two transparencies together make it seem that there's a dark line.  Maybe you have some margins/paddings that are running amuck?

Comment: can you please check my code how that can be reduce..plese help me to resolve this problem..

Comment: I'd highly suggest following the tutorial in the link I posted.  It only needs a few lines of code and some XML assets, but it is rather easy and you'll have complete control over the rendering of the tabs.